# How to call a function from multiple activities in Android?

Tags: android, viewmodel

Here is the scenario:
I am implementing on-demand feature delivery and

1. The download command is given in the `MainActivity,`
2. The progress is observed in a `BottomSheet`
3. If the downloading files for any reason, the error is shown in another activity, `ActivityB`. With an option to retry downloading.

I have tried creating a viewModel and sharing it between the Activities; that didn't work out because ViewModel is observed based on the owner. I can access the ViewModel in `ActivityB`, but that would be a new instance.

I can create a Singleton class and access it from all the activities but that would surely eat some memory.

Is there any optimized solution that you can think of? Please let me know.

Thank you